# How to add headers to dio http request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, put, dio

I have this put request that sends a file to the server, it requires a token as part of the headers. Please how do I add this token to the header while using Dio().put to make my request?

```
 Future<String> sendImage(File file) async {
    String token = storage.read('token');
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "CustomerProfilePicture":
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename: fileName),
    });
    Response response =
        await Dio().put(
            '$BASE_URL/Customers/Picture', data: formData);
    return response.statusMessage;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to put header to your DIO request:

```
await Dio().put('$BASE_URL/Customers/Picture',
    data: formData,
    options: Options(
      headers: {"key": "value"},
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass headers by using the `options` property for your request:

```
await Dio().put(
  '$BASE_URL/Customers/Picture',
  data: formData,
  options: Options(
    headers: {
      ...
    }
  ),
);
```

For more info, check the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).